# what is the output of program

Tags: c++, delete-operator

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  int *arr ;

   arr = new int[10];
  for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
        arr[i] = i;

    delete arr;
    for(int i=1 ; i<10;i++)
cout<<arr[i];

}
```

I was expecting a answer "123456789", but the answer was "023456789"

Comment: Undefined behavior.

Comment: Why in a World would you want to delete an array before using it?

Comment: @W.F. don't ask questions you don't want to know the answer to.

Comment: Please see the [tour] for the kinds of questions we expect here and also [ask].

Comment: i am not deleting entire array here. I tried deleting only first element(array name points to first element)

Comment: Unfortunately you can't selectively `delete` individual elements out of an array that was allocated by `new int[]`. So what you did broke things and thus lead to a nonsense result.

Answer (score 2):

Two problems here: you are deleting the array before using it, which results in undefined behavior.

Second, you are not using the correct form of delete, which is probably why only the first element is cleared.

The delete needs to be moved to after the print loop, and it needs to be changed to:

```
delete [] arr;
```

Comment: I am trying to delete only first element and then print the rest of the element. That is why i expected an answer "123456789"

Comment: The second loop will skip the first array element as written. Never delete just one element of an array.

Comment: Did not get "The second loop will skip the first array element as written"

Comment: @user1559214 by starting with an index of 1 instead of 0, the second loop automatically skips the first array element.

Answer (score -2):

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
  int *arr ;
   arr = new int[10];
  for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
        arr[i] = i;

    for(int i=1 ; i<10;i++)
    cout<<arr[i];
    delete [] arr;

}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this piece of code may answer the question, it is better to include a description of what the problem was, and how your code will tackle the given problem. For the future, here is some information, how to crack a awesome answer on Stack Overflow: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Improve your answer by using `{` and `}` for the `for` loops.  This is a good style habit for newbies.